# IndexedDB how to make method for transaction

Tags: javascript, class, transactions, indexeddb

I want to make a class method for transactions and get an error when I try to get an objectstore to work with it:
Uncaught TypeError: transaction.objectStore is not a function
at IndexedDB.saveToDataBase

the class method gets the value storeName and it is visible in console.log(storeName) === reminderList

```
    saveToDataBase(object, id) {        //storeName - name of the storage in the database,
                                        //object - the object being saved,
                                        //id - id of the object being saved
        console.log(object, id)
        console.log(storeName)
        console.log(database)


        // new transaction
        const transaction = this._makeTransaction(storeName, 'readwrite');
        const store = transaction.objectStore(storeName);   // an error occurs here!
        store.put(object, id);  // write record
        console.log(transaction)

    };

    _makeTransaction(storeName, mode) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let transaction = database.transaction(storeName, mode)
            transaction.oncomplete = () => {
                resolve(transaction); // success
                console.log(transaction)
            };

            transaction.onerror = () => {
                reject(transaction.error); // failure
            };
        })

    };
```

I did it this way and it works, but I don't understand why it doesn't work in the class method for transactions:

```
    saveToDataBase(object, id) {        //storeName - name of the storage in the database,
                                        //object - the object being saved,
                                        //id - id of the object being saved
                                        console.log(object, id)
                                        console.log(storeName)
                                        console.log(database)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            // new transaction
            const transaction = this._makeTransaction(storeName, 'readwrite');
            const store = transaction.objectStore(storeName);

            // write record
            store.put(object, id);  //

            transaction.oncomplete = () => {
                resolve(true); // success
            };

            transaction.onerror = () => {
                reject(transaction.error); // failure
            };

        })
    };

    _makeTransaction(storeName, mode) {
        let transaction = database.transaction(storeName, mode)
        return transaction
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your top `_makeTransaction` function returns a promise, not a transaction. Your bottom `_makeTransaction` function returns a transaction.

A promise, of course, doesn't have a `.objectStore` function.